# Converting dual boot Windows/Ubuntu to Ubuntu only

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, clonezilla

I have a desktop machine with 64 gig RAM and a 1 terabyte boot drive.. It started out as just Win 10 and then I made it dual boot with Ubuntu... My goal is to make it just boot directly into ubuntu and when i need windows for development, I'll use a Virtual box VM.. I have plenty of resource for that.

I have used Clonezilla a lot on other projects and  was wondering if this is the tool to use to do this. This must have been done before but haven't found the same case yet.

So basically I want to:

1. Clone the Ubuntu partition
2. use gparted to wipe out the boot drive and reformat just for Ubuntu
3. Make this new Ubuntu partition bootable
4. Restore the clonezilla image to this partition and have it boot directly into it...

Are these basic steps doable?
Thanks!
harry

Comment: Unless you need to extend the Ubuntu partition, you can format the Windows partition and run `sudo upgrade-grub`. Then you would not have to restore your clonezilla image (which is possible, but I don't know how to do that).

Comment: I almost always suggest new clean install with partitions you want and restore from your normal backup. If UEFI system, be sure to use gpt partitioning & install in UEFI boot mode. That does house clean of old data. It also confirms your backup includes everything you want or need. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2456011

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change from dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu to single-boot Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10690/how-do-i-change-from-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu-to-single-boot-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete all Windows partitions (C: drive, MS reserved partition etc.,) using GParted.
2. Run the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

3. If you want, reboot to a Linux live USB and resize your Linux partitions to fill up the space (or you can create a new partition in the reclaimed space to store things)