# Changing from Dual Boot to Full Ubuntu System

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 22.04

Just wondering, if I already have a machine running on dual boot (Wins + Ubuntu) and now I want to set it up as full Ubuntu, do I have to reformat my disk first?

Since I have a lot of data in my Ubuntu, wondering if it will eat up my memory if I don't reformat and just reinstall Ubuntu to remove Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change from dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu to single-boot Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10690/how-do-i-change-from-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu-to-single-boot-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

no, all you need to do is get into a *unix live iso ie gparted, and *carefully* remove the windows partition, then after removing it resize your Ubuntu partition to take up the freed space.